# how to save a df in text format using '\t' delimiter?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a file as text file with '\t' delimiter. How to do this? I am using pyspark2 and dataframes. I want code in Pyspark2 DF or SQL or RDD.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Df.rdd.map(lambda x: '\t'.join(x)).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile('/output/csv/6.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for reply. can i use df.write.csv('filepath',sep='\t')

Comment: I think as per your requiremnt  you need  to use saveAsTextFile

Comment: if i have 3 columns like col_1, col_2, col_3 in my file and i want to save in textfile with col_1 and col_2 delimited by | and col_3 delimited by : then how to do that?     required output:  col_1 | col_2 : col_3

Comment: the above code is not working

Comment: The following code worked for me. DF.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]+'\t'+x[1]+'\t'+x[2]).saveAsTextFile('/output/file/path')